# Export Google Earth Placemarks to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, kml, google-earth, land-classification

We were provided with a few geotagged photos, from those photos we were expected to mark more classification points around the region for the classes like water, built-up and barren land.

I was able to import those images into google earth using a KML file format using [this link](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/11/importing-geotagged-photos-into-google-earth.html). I further went on to mark and label required points around the region. This was done using google earth placemarks. I exported the KML file which has this format.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Barren land</name>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>78.01311981239444</longitude>
        <latitude>13.13658990287736</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>0.0456062423736624</heading>
        <tilt>30.00023885976806</tilt>
        <range>264.4081533793532</range>
        <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
    </LookAt>
    <styleUrl>#msn_track</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
        <coordinates>78.01311981239444,13.13658990287736,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Now I want to create a classifier with these labels.

My query is how to convert `Google Earth Placemark KML` to shapefile with proper labels for classification **using a code in python and not a tool**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for converting **KML to SHP** you can use an open source library [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/). For conversion in command line tool you can type:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' output.shp input.kml
```

Of course you can put this in bash script. But if you really need to have this done in python, you can call command in you python script:

```
import os
os.system("ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' output.shp input.kml")
```

In my opinion using Google Earth is not most suitable tool to do the classification on imagery. If you need to stick to free and open source tools I would recommend **QGIS**, where you can do manual classification (creating shapefiles manually). Maybe there also are some tools for automatic classification, but I'm not aware of them.

You can also use more professional tools like **ArcGIS**, **Erdas Imagine** or **ENVI**, in which you can manually classify data on your imagery or use tools and options for automatic classification.

More on classification basics can be easily done with googling, e.g. http://gisgeography.com/image-classification-techniques-remote-sensing/

Comment: Hey thanks!! a lot !! I have to code it all the pipeline. Because we need to integrate it to a system. Can you point me out in the direction of crop classification using satellite images in python. So far I have these two [this](https://www.machinalis.com/blog/python-for-geospatial-data-processing/) and [this](https://github.com/brmagnuson/LandFallowingInEarthEngine)

Comment: Well your links looks promising, I guess you have to test what suits your needs best. Maybe also you can have a try with **GRASS GIS**. It has options for image classification: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_classification and you can integrate it with Python: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python or shell scripts https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Shell_scripting